# How to include a LinkedList to my struct program with char*

Tags: c

I am creating a program that asks the user input for their first names within a struct with a char pointer that dynamically allocates memory using malloc. How would I include a LinkedList into this program?

```c
#define MAX_NUM_PASSPORTS 5
typedef struct passport{
    char *getFirstNameFromApplicant;
    unsigned long long int id;
}Passport; 

int main()
{
    char *firstname = (char*) malloc(MAX_BUFF_SIZE * sizeof(char));
    if (firstname == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed!"); 
        exit(1);
    } 

    Passport *passports = (Passport*) malloc(MAX_NUM_PASSPORTS * sizeof(Passport));
    if (passports == NULL){
         fprintf(stderr, "Failed!"); 
         exit(2);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_NUM_PASSPORTS; i++){
          Passport *temp_passport = &passports[i];
          temp_passport->id = I;
          printf("Please enter first name of the owner for Passport with ID=%d: \n", I);

          get_input(firstname, MAX_BUFF_SIZE-1);

          temp_passport->getFirstNameFromApplicant = (char*) malloc(strlen(firstname)*sizeof(char) + 1);
          if (temp_passport->getFirstNameFromApplicant == NULL){
              fprintf(stderr, "Passport Name Malloc Failed!"); 
              exit(3);
          }
          strcpy(temp_passport->getFirstNameFromApplicant, firstname);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_NUM_PASSPORTS; i++){
        printf("\nPassport id:%d has been succesfully renewed. It belongs to %s",passports[i].id, passports[i].getFirstNameFromApplicant);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For what use do you want to use LinkedList for? Please provide the details.

Comment: Hi, it is for my homework. I know the functionality of a LinkedList and able to program it with a static array of names but am lost how to program one dynamically into this program.

Comment: So, you need to create LL of passports? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Have you done a search on how to implement a linked list? There are literally thousands of posts and examples. It's not reasonable just to ask someone to restructure your code when you haven't even shown any attempt to research or implement the basics of what you need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of appending at the end of the head of a LinkedList.

It contains an `append` function which will add nodes to the end of head of the list.
It also contains a `printll` function to print the whole list.

I guess those functions will assist you to do further tasks. And for now, I have *not* included `free` functionality which I think you should figure out.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_NUM_PASSPORTS 5
#define MAX_BUFF_SIZE 10

typedef struct passport{
    char *getFirstNameFromApplicant;
    size_t id;
    struct passport * next;
}Passport; 

void append(Passport**,size_t,char*);
void printll(Passport*);

int main()
{
    char *firstname = malloc(MAX_BUFF_SIZE);
    if (firstname == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed!"); 
        exit(1);
    } 
    
    Passport *head = NULL;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < MAX_NUM_PASSPORTS; i++){
        printf("Please enter first name of the owner for Passport with ID=%ld: \n", i);
        //get_input is the function from OP, I used fgets(firstname,MAX_BUFF_SIZE,stdin)
        get_input(firstname, MAX_BUFF_SIZE-1);
        append(&head,i,firstname);
    }

    printll(head);
    return 0;
}

void printll(Passport * currentPtr)
{
    while(currentPtr != NULL){
        printf("\nPassport id: %ld has been succesfully renewed. It belongs to %s",currentPtr->id, currentPtr->getFirstNameFromApplicant);
        currentPtr = currentPtr->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void append(Passport ** head, size_t value,char * s)
{
    Passport * currentPtr = *head;
    Passport * newNode = NULL;

    if ((newNode = malloc(1*sizeof(Passport)))== NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Passport Node Malloc Failed!"); 
        exit(2);
    }

    if ((newNode->getFirstNameFromApplicant = malloc(strlen(s)+1))== NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Passport Name Malloc Failed!"); 
        exit(3);
    }
    strcpy(newNode->getFirstNameFromApplicant, s);
    newNode->id = value;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    if(*head == NULL){
        *head = newNode;
    }

    else{
        while(currentPtr->next != NULL){
            currentPtr = currentPtr->next;
        }
        currentPtr->next = newNode;
    } 
}
```